# How can I list all of the keywords in my images

Tags: windows, list, keyword, xmp

I would like to analyse my images by keywords. Is there a program that can produce a text file containing a list of files with the keyword tags that they contain?
e.g. File1.jpg,Birds,Kestrel
File2.jpg,Birds,Blackbird
etc.

Thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: Consider utilizing [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/). Then via your command-line you can run the following command: `exiftool -recurse -quiet -csv -xmp-dc:subject /path/to/my/image/folder/`. _(**Note**: you’ll need to redefine the `/path/to/my/image/folder/` part in the aforementioned command as necessary)_.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried that, but it is too slow. In the end I used IMatch export text.